# IP address not pointing to domain name I expect it to

Tags: ip-address, domains, godaddy

I am administering this site: http://www.epicperks.com.

As per GoDaddy's control panel as well as [this service](https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html), the IP address pointing to http://www.epicperks.com is `50.63.210.1`.

However, when I visit the two address (one domain name, one IP), I see completely different results.

The domain name shows the website as I intend it to be but the IP address shows `pageok` message.

What is going on here?

Comment: Is this shared hosting?

Comment: It is the Deluxe package shown here: https://ca.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=9009

Comment: OK, based on that page I'm fairly certain that it is shared hosting, meaning that they host multiple web sites on the same server/ip address and differentiate between web sites by way of host headers or name-based virtual hosts. So when you navigate to the ip address you are navigating to the default web site/page on that server, not to your web site. The web server uses the client host headers to determine what web site to direct the client to. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Yup, the minute you mentioned shared hosting, it hit me. Thanks. If you wanted to put it up as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: You will only see your website via your IP with a dedicated IP address. And oh yeah, don't use GoDaddy.

Comment: Apparently you're not the only one wondering! https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=godaddy+pageok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, based on that page I'm fairly certain that it is shared hosting, meaning that they host multiple web sites on the same server/ip address and differentiate between web sites by way of host headers or name-based virtual hosts. So when you navigate to the ip address you are navigating to the default web site/page on that server, not to your web site. The web server uses the client host headers to determine what web site to direct the client to.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx